# Waiting for AJAX to perform a client operation

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm calling a page with ajax, which should run a javascript code before it returns

for example:

**differentPage.php**

```
..code
<div id="awesomeDiv"></div>
<script>
 $("#awesomeDiv").html("it is very awesome");
</script>
..code
```

Now in my page, let's call it "myPage.php" I call an ajax for differentPage.php and need to get the html inside awesomeDiv, like this:

**myPage.php**

```
$.ajax({
 'url':  'differentPage.php',
 'dataType': 'html',
 'success': function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    myFunc(data);
   }
});

function myFunc(data){
 var htmlData = $($("<div>").html(data)[0]);
 var awesomeDiv = htmlData.find("#awesomeDiv"); 
 alert(awesomeDiv);
}
```

It alerts an empty string.

Is there a way to tell the ajax call to wait until all client code was ended?

Comment: `$($("<div>").html(data)[0]);` is just awful - if you're returning HTML, just do `$(data)` or `$("<div>").html(data)` without the extra surround.

Comment: Thank you,  @CollinGrady. `$(data)` is better indeed.

Answer (score -1):

It's not very safe, but it's a solution. You should:

1. append the HTML-code that comes from server
2. execute scripts that come from server

So, the code should be approximately:

```
function myFunc(data){
    var htmlData = $("<div>").html(data).appendTo('#container'),
        awesomeDiv = $('#awesomeDiv', htmlData);
    $('script', obj).each(function(script) {
        eval(script.innerHTML);
    }); 
    alert(awesomeDiv);
}
```

**NOTE:** it's not safe to transport scripts in this way! Much better to include your scripts to the HEAD (with tag SCRIPT) and then manipulate them.